# How to keep previous data and add more data in array React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm using picker with numbers 1 to 4, when the user selects any number from picker like I select 3 then 3 text inputs will be shown and I will enter something in these three input fields, and I'm saving values of these 3 inputs in an array. When I hit save and I want to edit it again like I've changed my mind and I want to add 2 more input fields and when I select 2 than[image] the previous 2 replace with new 2 empty text inputs but I want to keep the previous as well.
Here are the screenshots

[image]

here is the code.
**For a number of text input based on picker value.**

```
 {this.state.storeArr.map((item, index) => (
          <TextInput
            key={index}
            style={[
              styles.input,
              {backgroundColor: theme.colors.lightGray},
            ]}
            placeholder=" Name "
            keyboardType={'default'}
            placeholderTextColor="gray"
            value={item}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, index)}
          />
        ))}

onChangeText = (text, index) => {
    const {storeArr} = this.state;
    const arr = [...storeArr];
    arr[index] = text;
    this.setState({storeArr: arr}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.storeArr);
    });
    console.log(storeArr);
  };
```

**here is the code of setting no of "" in the array based on picker value**

```
  setInput = (value) => {
    this.setState({storeArr: Array(value).fill('')});
  };
```

**in **setinput** function I want to handle to keep the previous strings in the array and add more as per picker value selected using Array(value).fill('')**

Comment: push your codes to github and leave a link here, i will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the setInput function:

```
setInput = (value) => {
    this.setState({ storeArr: value - this.state.storeArr.length >= 0
        ? [...this.state.storeArr, ...Array(value - this.state.storeArr.length).fill('')]
        : this.state.storeArr.filter((_, index) => index <= value)
    });
};
```

Comment: Duy Nguyen Thanks it worked partially ,If I select 4 it show perfectly if i select 3 nothing happend 4 remained,if I select 2 then shows 3 and if I select 1 shows 2